# OpenCV cv::CalcHist - no matching function

Tags: ios, opencv

I am trying to calculate the histogram for a part of an image, prior to calculating the cam shift. I have followed an example - but bviously not closely enough, as i get an error saying there is no matching function call for CalcHist with the parameters i am sending...

```
float max_val = 0.f;
Mat hsv;
int hbins = 30, sbins = 32;
int histSize[] = {hbins, sbins};
float hranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float sranges[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* ranges[] = { hranges, sranges };
int channels[] = {0, 1};
cv::cvtColor(image(_cars[i]), hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

cv::calcHist( &hsv, 1, channels, Mat(), // do not use mask
              thisCar.hist, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
```

Comment: what is `thisCar.hist`? Is it of type `OutputArray`?

Comment: thisCar.hist is a CvHistogram*

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems with this as well. However, this version of your code worked for me.

```
float max_val = 0.f;
cv::Mat img;
cv::Mat hsv;
cv::MatND hist;
int hbins = 30, sbins = 32;
int histSize[] = {hbins, sbins};
float hranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float sranges[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* ranges[] = { hranges, sranges };
int channels[] = {0, 1};
cv::cvtColor(img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::calcHist(&hsv, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
```